# Get Elements from an XML file per namespace + Tag name

Tags: java, xml

For example take these two XML Strings:

1.

```
 <D:current-user-principal xmlns:D="DAV:">
        <D:href>/principals/users/cdaboo</D:href>
      </D:current-user-principal>
```

2.

```
<d:current-user-principal xmlns:d="DAV:">
        <d:href>/principals/users/cdaboo</d:href>
      </d:current-user-principal>
```

they are basically the same but with the difference in `xmlns:D="DAV:"` `xmlns:d="DAV:"`.

When i find the current-user-principal element via Java XML DOM API I cannot simple use the `getElementsByTagName` method.
This program fails:

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = null;

        doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><D:current-user-principal xmlns:D=\"DAV:\">\n" +
                "<D:href>/test/for/stackoverflow</D:href>\n" +
                "</D:current-user-principal>")));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList currentUserPrincipal = doc.getElementsByTagName("d:current-user-principal");
        System.out.println(currentUserPrincipal.item(0).getTextContent());
```

because i search for "d:current-user-principal" instead of "D:current-user-principal".

Is there an easy way to achiece this with Java DOM API or any other xml parser library?

Answer (score 3):

You can look for element using the *NS* methods like `getElementsByTagNameNS`.

You just don't use the *prefix* but the namespace itself.

You need to create a namespace aware factory.

```java
        String docstr = " <D:current-user-principal xmlns:D=\"DAV:\">\r\n" + 
                "        <D:href>/principals/users/cdaboo</D:href>\r\n" + 
                "      </D:current-user-principal>";
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        ByteArrayInputStream docBytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(docstr.getBytes("utf-8"));
        Document doc = builder.parse(docBytes);

        Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
        String uri = root.getNamespaceURI();
        NodeList elementsByTagNameNS = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(uri , "href");

        Element node = (Element) elementsByTagNameNS.item(0);
        System.out.println(node.getTextContent()); // Prints: /principals/users/cdaboo
```